# Using Telethon to forward messages to a topic/thread in a different group

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

So I am trying to create a simple script that forwards messages from one Telegram group to a Topic or a Thread in a different group... I have the following but it never seems to forward messages, and I am not sure how to specify the topic I prefer it to forward too

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

API_ID = '2####1'
API_HASH = '9#######7'
SESSION_NAME = 'Forward-Rose-and-Kim'

SOURCE_GROUP_ID = -948809343
DESTINATION_GROUP_ID = -1001805701971

## I'm not sure if there should be an extra variable, I tried using DESTINATION_GROUP_ID = -1001805701971/6 with '6' being the topic I... but this doesn't work as well

client = TelegramClient(SESSION_NAME, API_ID, API_HASH)

async def forward_message_to_destination(message):
    await client.send_message(DESTINATION_GROUP_ID, message)
    print(f"Message forwarded: {message.text}")

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=SOURCE_GROUP_ID))
async def forward_messages(event):
    message = event.message
    await forward_message_to_destination(message)

with client:
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

just for sake of clarify, this works forwarding from a group to a group, but not to a topic in a group and I am not sure how to point where I want the message to go within `DESTINATION_GROUP_ID = -1001805701971` as there are like 6 or 7 different topics in that channel

Comment: You need to know the topic id first, there is a request for that or figure it out yourself through normal Telegram apps link copy, then just use reply_to=topic_id in send_message to send to specific topic.. (in the api topics are threads, all messages reply to first topic message more specifically the topic created service message)

Comment: @MustA Thank you so much, dont know how I missed that. updated to ```await client.send_message(DESTINATION_GROUP_ID, message, reply_to=6)``` and working perfect now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated to `await client.send_message(DESTINATION_GROUP_ID, message, reply_to=6)` and working perfect now

The `relpy_to=6` being the thread ID